# MySQL statement syntax error on INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong in this query? When executed, it shows this message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN category ON product.CategoryID = category.CategoryI WHERE product.Pro' at line 1

```
$filter = "SELECT product.ProductID,
           product.ProductName,
           category.CategoryName,
           product.ProductPrice,
           product.QuantityAvailable, "
           . "product.AddedDate,product.Status"
           . "INNER JOIN category ON product.CategoryID = category.CategoryID "
           . "WHERE product.ProductName LIKE '%$productName%' 
          AND category.CategoryName = '$productCategory' 
          AND " . "product.ProductPrice BETWEEN $productPriceFrom AND       $productPriceTo 
          AND product.QuantityAvailable BETWEEN $productQuantityFrom AND $productQuantityTo 
          AND " . "product.AddedDate BETWEEN '$productCreatedFrom' AND '$productCreatedTo' 
          AND product.Status = '$productstatus'";
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to read as is. Could you `echo` the query before executing it and share the output here?

Comment: You are missing the `FROM` in the query.

Comment: what the pretty hard to read ??? try now .....

Comment: ooooooooh yes i am forget the from

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `FROM` clause in query.

Replace `"product.AddedDate,product.Status "` with

```
"product.AddedDate,product.Status FROM product "
```

Comment: thanks ...  be success now

Comment: but now show this message (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND AND product.QuantityAvailable BETWEEN AND AND product.AddedDate BETWEEN '' at line 1) what the wrong in the and??

Comment: You have two ANDs in a row. Do you know SQL or is this just a copy and paste? I don't want to be rude, but these are pretty basic errors. I would take the time to learn it fully so that you can solve these problems on your own.

Comment: @KhaledALHajSalem `$productQuantityFrom`, `productQuantityTo` etc. variables are empty.

Comment: @siride i am on wrong but some times some problems that happened ... in overview thank you ....

Comment: what the right ....???